# Checking 'checked' property selects radio button

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons, neither of them is checked by default, and depending on which one is clicked/checked i should collect text from two different textboxes.

```
if ($("#70").prop("checked", true)) {
    var s=$('input[name="a"]').val();
}
else {
    var s=$('input[name="b"]').val();
}
```

The problem is that if I check the second one, with id '60', the first one gets the checked property, If I set the if statement to check the second one, id='60', then the same thing happens but this time the second one gets checked.

This is the code for the radio buttons

```
<label id="a" for="70" style="width:50px">
          <input type="radio" name="brojBodova" value="70" id="70">70
    </label> 
    <label id="b" for="60" style="width:50px;">    
          <input type="radio" name="brojBodova" value="60" id="60">60
    </label>
```

Comment: You need to read (or re-read) the documentation for the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method: `$("#70").prop("checked", true)` sets the `"checked"` property to `true`, it doesn't ascertain if it is checked, and that method, also returns a jQuery object, which is truthy in the context of an `if` assessment.

Comment: The condition you are looking for is either `if ($("#70").attr("checked"))` or `if $("#70").is(":checked"))`. But I second @DavidThomas's advice. You will find if very difficult to code with so little information about the tools you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try remove second param in `.prop()` method! it will work!

- Call `$("#70").prop("checked")` when you want get value of `checked` attribute
- Call `$("#70").prop("checked", true)` when you want set value for `checked` attribute

  `if ($("#70").prop("checked")) {
      var s=$('input[name="a"]').val();
  }else {
      var s=$('input[name="b"]').val();
  }`

Answer (score -1):

**If the buttons are in the same group they need to share the same name= attribute**

Fiddle Below

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(ele){
var s = $(this).attr('value');
$("#result").html(s);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="a" for="70" style="width:50px">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="70" id="70">70
</label>
<label id="b" for="60" style="width:50px;">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="60" id="60">60
</label>

<div id="result">
Click a button
</div>
```